# Rails 3 checkbox with filename value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to know if its possible to set value of a checkbox other than 0 and 1.

In my form, i have a list of file name with selectbox to select wich file we want to attach to the form.

for now, i have something like this from a <% form_for @space do |e| %>

```
<% for space_photo in @space.space_photo %>
  <div style="float:left;">Photo <%= e.check_box 'space_photo', :value => space_photo.photo() %></div>
<%end%>
```

but when i see the form, my checkbox have value=1 but i want to have the value of filename does i need a hidden textfield? or something like that?

After adding bracket [] to my checbox like this 
    <% for space_photo in @space.space_photo %>
        Photo <%= e.check_box 'space_photo[]', {}, space_photo.photo %>
    <%end%>

i use this way to debug

```
render :text => "The object is #{params}"
```

the result are

```
space_photonotespace_id11
```

space_photo are empty.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I second the notion that this is not really the typical use of a checkbox.  Nevertheless, there is a way to accomplish what you want.

There is a little trick going on with checkboxes.  Rails adds a hidden field so that the specified unchecked value is sent.

Take a look at the checkbox specs here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

You can use code like this to get what you want:

```
<%= e.check_box 'space_photo', {}, space_photo.photo, "" %>
```

Where the blank hash `{}` fills the options argument.

**UPDATE**

To get an array of values back you need to use array syntax.  Just add `[]` to the end of the checkbox name.  I haven't tested this, but you might need to check for the blank values in your controller action.

```
<%= e.check_box 'space_photo[]', {}, space_photo.photo, "" %>
```

Comment: thanks works good! After that, i just need to do a space_photo.each to check every files?

Comment: i checked what you suggested, but this return me only the last checked element, i need to get all checked.

Comment: Hi Wizard, i tried your way to do, but nothing worked. If i if use [] in my checkbox name, i have no result in my debug show, i edited my post to show you the result.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  The whole purpose of a checkbox is to represent a two-state, on/off or true/false scenario.  If you need help implementing whatever function you are speaking of, perhaps you could give a description of what types of models and associations you are dealing with.

Comment: I have a list of photos. someone enter informations on a form, and select all photos he wants to be linked to the space. this send a mail with selected photo.

Comment: @neimad You need to be very careful that you do not open a security leak.  Make sure that a user can't tamper with the filenames and download other files besides the photos.